# How to get bus stations /stops around a specific location from Google Maps in Android?

Tags: android, maps

I need to get some bus stations/stops's location (lat/lng) around a specific location from Google Maps but I don't know where I should start to do.I have consulted some documents and it uses Google Maps API to solve this problem.Could you please guide me the way to use Google API to get a bus station's location.If possible,you please send me your code! I'd be very grateful for your help !

Comment: Word to the wise: Spend more time learning, less time asking for code. What have you tried? What are your ideas? What problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use google Place API with gson to query for your nearby bus station.

Comment: so,can I get all bus stations with a specific distance from my location (1km,2km...) instead of the nearest one ?